# residue complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

If  $f$ has a pole of order N at $z_0$, then we have that $f(z)=\sum_{n=-N}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$, Setting $g(z)=(z-z_0)^Nf(z)$. The result is that $Res(f,z_0)=\frac{f^{N-1}(z_0)}{(N-1)!}$. How is this result  happening? I have looked at differentiating  $g(z)=(z-z_0)^N\sum_{n=-N}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$ $N-1$ times, but then I cannot isolate the $c_{-1}$ which is the residue with out additional factors in it. I am at a loss.

Comment: In the expression for $g$, bring the outer factor under the summation.

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply both sides of the expression by $(z-z_0)^N$ you obtain a new series on the RHS which can be written:

$$(z-z_0)^Nf(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n $$

It's indices start at zero because by multiplying by $(z-z_0)^N$ you have eliminated all of the factors of $z-z_0$ in the denominators. Before multiplying, the residue was the coefficient on the $1/(z-z_0)$ term of the series, so now in the new series it is the coefficient on the $(z-z_0)^{N-1}$ term.

Taking the derivative $N-1$ times on the RHS all the terms before the $(z-z_0)^{N-1}$ term become zero, and

$$ \frac{d^{N-1}}{dz^{N-1}}\left[a_{N-1}(z-z_0)^{N-1}\right]=a_{N-1}(N-1)!$$

And then, all of the terms after that end up with some factor of $z-z_0$. So when you take the limit as $z$ goes to $z_0$ all that is left on the RHS is $a_{N-1}(N-1)!$ Putting all this together you can say then that:

$$ a_{N-1} = \lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{1}{(N-1)!}\frac{d^{N-1}}{dz^{N-1}}\left((z-z_0)^Nf(z) \right)$$